# Firestore cannot upload List

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i try to store a new item in a previous from Firestore downloaded ArrayList>. The download process is working but after editing the list, i cannot upload it again, because firestore says it needs to be a Map. Therefore i tried to use 
`Map<String, Object> listValue = new HashMap<>();
        listValue.put("shoppingLists", Arrays.asList(shoppingLists));`
The problem is if i use this code it says nested arrays are not supported. Here is the complete code:

```
 private void addNewDataToList(int i, ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> shoppingLists, SellerObject soa) {
    String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> products = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>) shoppingLists.get(i).get("products");
    String title = (String) shoppingLists.get(i).get("listname");

    HashMap<String, Object> newProduct = new HashMap<>();
    newProduct.put("sellerId", soa.getId());
    newProduct.put("productId", productId);
    products.add(newProduct);

    HashMap<String, Object> newListObject = new HashMap<>();
    newListObject.put("listname", title);
    newListObject.put("products", products);
    shoppingLists.set(i, newListObject);
    ArrayList<ShoppingListObject> finalList = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Object> listValue = new HashMap<>();
    listValue.put("shoppingLists", Arrays.asList(shoppingLists));


    db.collection("Users").document(userid)

            .set(listValue, SetOptions.merge())
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                }
            });
}
```